# Problems in importing split in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm practicing on python 3.7.0 shell.

How can I import `split()` ?

Below is the error:

> > > from string import split
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >           from string import split
> > >       ImportError: cannot import name 'split' from 'string'

Comment: `split()` is built-in, no need to import.

Comment: The `string` module is hardly used, or needed, these days, maybe your tutorial is very old?

Comment: directly call `split()` on string type objects. `<string_var>.split()` , This splits on spaces. And providing a delimiter splits on that delimiter.

Comment: @VineethSai: `string.split()` does not work, that's the point:  `AttributeError: module 'string' has no attribute 'split'`.  Did you mean `str.split()`?

Comment: Oops, I meant <string>.split(). string as a variable, edited it, Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have to run your code on Python 2.x shell

In Python 3.x, string module does not have split method. so, it does not work on Python 3.x shell and you get such error